# Сохранение файла после загрузки

Tags: c#

Привет. Написал код для загрузки файла на диск D.

```
 WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
        string downloadFileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName("http://kssss.esy.es/news.txt");

        myWebClient.DownloadFile("http://kssss.esy.es/news.txt", @"D:/" + downloadFileName);
```

А теперь пытаюсь, чтобы сохранялась вот здесь:

```
(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + @"/Grand Hack/ver/version.txt")
```

Но всегда вылазеет ошибка, помогите!

Comment: Прошу помидорками не кидаться )))

Comment: Всё решил проблемму

Comment: @Егор Глухов, По возможности публикуйте ответы на форуме, они могут помочь многим в будущем.@Егор Глухов, По возможности публикуйте ответы на форуме, они могут помочь многим в будущем.